# Cloud Firestore Role Based Access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement role-based security for Cloud Firestore. Am I understanding correctly that users retrieving stories in Google's example at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access would see the roles other users have?
How would one design against that?
I assume by using another collection & using Get?

Answer (score 0):

Tad vague, but...

I am implementing role-based access in an app, but not following the example, for the very reason you mention:  if a user can read a document, then they read *all* of the document.

My approach is a bit less direct.

The roles are stored in more secure records where only someone authorized to create the roles has access.

- A Cloud Function is used for a user to fetch role information - that
  way the user does not have direct access, but the secure back-end can
  validate and "filter" the data appropriately (in this case, whether they are "managers" of a business property)
- Another Cloud Function adds role information onto the Users account
  Token as customClaims (has to be done in secure environment, not client)
- Security rules validate access against the customClaims - which all
  happens in a secure environment (no need to trust the browser)

More convoluted, but it does control role visibility.